# Is it possible in Babylon.js to make an object's transparency be driven by viewing angle?

Tags: javascript, babylonjs

For example imagine a cube. As you look straight onto the cube, the side of the cube which is facing the camera is fully transparent.

Then you rotate the cube or the camera around the cube, and as you do this, the side that was transparent starts to become more and more opaque.

Is this possible in Babylon and how would this possibly work?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **backfill culling**.

As you can see in this example, the mesh plane has two sides.
The front side is visible, however, the back side is transparent:
https://playground.babylonjs.com/#Q9VZS9#4

To achieve the same result with the box, we must invert the faces: https://playground.babylonjs.com/#XJT131

```
box = MeshBuilder.CreateBox("box", { size: 2, sideOrientation: Mesh.BACKSIDE });
```

Comment: This comes close. But it doesn't seem to allow the polygons to become transparent gradually based on angle to the camera. When you look in a 45 degrees angle onto a surface, for example, this surface would become 50% transparent. If you look straight onto that surface, it would be 100% transparent. I think I need custom shaders for this?